# What files to share from my VB.NET GUI project?

Tags: c#, vb.net, git, visual-studio-2010, project

I have a GUI application that has been developed using VB.NET/C# using Visual Studio. One of the ways for collaborating and also keeping track of versions is via repos on GitHub,  BitBucket, etc.

What files should I push to the online rep? What files will a collaborator need to replicate the GUI or use this GUI along with their own GUI?

.vb/.cs and .resx are Needed. What about .vbproj?  Are files under "My Project" necessary as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that with your question in reality you really mean, what files should I ignore ?

Basically what you want to do is put some unnecessary files into the .gitignore to avoid sharing unneeded files.

Take a look at [this project](https://github.com/github/gitignore) that maintains a list of all gitignore files by programming language.

Comment: Thanks! that was very helpful